# Creating custom API in xcart

Tags: php, x-cart

I am using xcart for developing my custom API's. But I am not able to figure out how the existing API's of xcart are working.

I have found an existing API which gives the product details corresponding to the product id.

```
API - http:///admin.php?target=RESTAPI&_key=rest-api-key&_path=product/1
```

Can you please tell the routing and controller for the above API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All default controllers are located in /XLite/Controller/ directory and all modules' controllers in /XLite/Module/~Developer-ID~/~Module-ID~/Controller ones.

The particular controller for the page in question is \XLite\Module\XC\RESTAPI\Controller\Admin\RESTAPI.